# Program won't recognize all functions from my header file (Except two of them)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am implementing a money.h header file in order to overload basic mathematical operators to work on money objects. The class includes 12 overloaded operators, a constructor that sets dollars and cents to 0, and one that calls the set functions, a set_dollars() and set_cents() function, and a get_total() function. (The set_dollars(), constructors, and get_total are auto-inlined). The program recognizes the overloaded assignment operator, and the set_cents function, but any time I try to perform an operation (such as ob1 + ob2), the compiler completely ignores the statement.

I have been trying different methods of implementing the header file, and doing research, but can't seem to find a fix to the problem. I have removed the majority of style and comments to keep the program as simple as possible.

The following code shows the libraries, class, and 2 of the overloaded functions in the header file "money.h".

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class money
{
    int   cents,   // Whole number cents amount
          dollars; // Whole number dollars amount

public:

    // Constructor, creates a money amount
    money() {cents   = 0, 
             dollars = 0;}
    money(float amount) {set_dollars(amount),
                         set_cents  (amount); }

    // Sets the dollars and cents values
    void set_cents  (float amount);
    void set_dollars(float amount) {dollars = (int)amount;}


    // Gets the total money amount
    float get_total() {return((float) dollars +
                       (float) (cents * .01f));}

    // Overloaded functions
    money operator=  (money assignment);
   money operator+  (money addition);
   money operator-  (money subtraction);
   money operator*  (money multiplication);
   money operator/  (money division);
   money operator+= (money add_into);
   int   operator== (money equality);
   int   operator!= (money inequality);
   float operator<< (int amount);
   float operator>> (int amount);
   money operator++ ();
   money operator++ (int notused);
};


//*** Sets the cents value of the money amount ***

void money::set_cents(float amount)
{
   // Removes the dollar amount from the total
   amount -= (float) dollars;

   // Rounds the cents to the next whole cent
   if (amount >= 0.00f)
      amount += 0.005f;
   else 
      amount -= 0.005f;

   // Moves the decimal point to make cents a mixed number
   amount *= 100.0f;

   // Truncates the decimal value of cents and stores it into a whole 
   // value of cents
   cents = (int) amount;

   // Checks and distributes the remaining cents and dollars
   if (cents < -99)
   {
      cents   -= 100;
      dollars -= 1;
   }
   else if (cents > 99)
   {
      cents   += 100;
      dollars += 1;
   }

   return;
}


//*** Overloaded assignment operator ***
money money::operator=(money assignment)
{
   dollars = assignment.dollars;
   cents   = assignment.cents;
   return *this;
}

//*** Overloaded addition operator ***

money money::operator+(money addition)
{
   money temp_amount;

   temp_amount.dollars = dollars + addition.dollars;
   temp_amount.cents   = cents   + addition.cents;
   set_cents(temp_amount.get_total());

   return temp_amount;
}
```

---

Following code is from main cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "money.h"
using namespace std;

//*** Main Function ***
   // Print the "complied and linked properly" message
   cout << "\n\n  Your money.h compiled and linked properly, indicating"
        << "\n  all required overloaded operator and member functions"
        << "\n  are present. However this DOES NOT mean the functions"
        << "\n  are working correctly.   YOU MUST completely test all"
        << "\n  your functions yourself, to ensure their reliability.";

   // Normal program termination
   cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n";


   // The code which follows checks to see if all required money class
   // overloaded operator and member functions are present in the
   // included "money.h" file.

   // Test for the presence of the constructors
   money ob1,        // Uninitialized money object
         ob2(0.00f); // Initialized   money object

   // Test for the presence of the set member functions
   ob1.set_dollars(0.00f); // ERR: Class "money" has no member "set_dollars"
   ob1.set_cents(0.00f);   // ***Works fine***

   // Test for the presence of the get member function
   ob1.get_total(); // ERR: Class "money" has no member "get_total"

   // Test for the presence of the overloaded operator functions
   ob1 = ob2;
   ob1 + ob2; // ERR: No operator "+"  matches these operands. Operand types
   ob1 - ob2;
   ob1 * ob2; 
   ob1 / ob2;  
   ob1 += ob2; 
   ob1 == ob2; 
   ob1 != ob2;
   ob1 << 1;  
   ob1 >> 1;   
   ++ob1;      
   ob1++;      

   cout << ob1.get_total();
   return 0;


}
```

No compiler errors show up, and the program works fine. Whenever I try to do an operation such as "ob1 + ob2" and output it, the compiler completely ignores it and still runs showing only the heading

The operators are underlined in red and say that there is no such operator in money.h, and that it is supposed to be money + money, When it is...

Comment: "underlined in red" is not a real error message. What error messages for which line of your code will be thrown by the compiler?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted it when i was erasing the other unnecessary comments (Style stuff)                                                                                        ERR: No operator "+"  matches these operands. Operand types

Comment: Also it isn't thrown by the compiler, it is underlined in red in the code editor. The program compiles and works, but every function except the two named are completely ignored.

Comment: So please reduce your code here to exactly that part which is not working. Nobody here reads useless code around the real problem. Simply edit your question!

Comment: The issue here is that I have no idea where the issue is, because there are no compiler errors. All the code that is there is necessary to understand the point of the code. For all I know all of it should be working and none of it is. There is no one direct question. The majority of the code anyway is comments to help direct anyone reading the code...

Comment: I showed the set cents function cause it works, and the overloaded addition operator cause it doesn't work. I showed the class cause that helps to understand what the other code is working with. Then i showed main to show what is supposed to actually execute, and what part of it isn't.

Comment: What happens when you **compile** the code? If you get error messages, post them. If not, then what's the question? <g>

Comment: I realized part of the issue was the accidental return statement. I fixed that part but didn't post it back on here so my bad. I'm getting an error code that says that none of the overloaded operators are applicable to the class.

Comment: You have no main either? I see there was a comment referencing the start of it but is it actually there in your main cpp?

Comment: `#include "pch.h"` in a header is odd. Not sure what Visual Studio does with it, though.

Comment: If the first file is money.h, then the main.cpp is including "pch.h" twice.

Comment: Also, when testing the operators, be careful if you're not resetting the obj1 and obj2 amounts before each test. Otherwise you'll have to keep track of the correct state of each obj after each test to ensure you're getting the right result at the end.

Comment: Any reason you *need* to use *precompiled headers*?  Time your rebuilds with PCH on and with PCH off.  Measure the difference.  Is the difference significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled and linked your code with no warnings/errors by just adding your main back, removing pch.h, and removing the uses of your undefined operators `-` -> `++`.

Comment: It's unusual, but you **can** overload binary `operator+` as a member function. That's what the code here does. The left-hand-side is the object that it's being called on, so the function only takes one explicit argument.

Comment: Oh, you're right I overlooked that part of the implementation here.

Comment: Everything about my colleges style is different lol. Sorry about that.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect what fixed the compiler/linker errors. At this time, no other errors are known. It definitely uses the '+' operator with these fixes, though there's other logical errors that will need to be addressed.

Comment: I got it figured out, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that, because you have a user-defined copy assignment operator, you should also provide a user-defined copy constructor.  You can achieve that by adding the following to your class definition:

```
money (const money &copy_from) = default;
```

Better yet, remove your `operator=` function as you don't actually need it - the compiler will generate one for you that copies all the data members, which seems to be what you want.  Then you don't need the copy constructor either.

Also, some of your function signatures are wrong.  Your assignment operator, for example, should be:

```
money &operator= (const money &);
```

and your `operator+` would usually be:

```
money operator+ (const money &);
```

Doing this will avoid unnecessary copies.

Finally, read up on the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  In your case, the rule of zero would apply.